# How to select columns based on indices stored in a vector in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, subset, correlation

I am trying to select columns from a dataframe that have a correlation greater than a desired cutoff. I am using findCorrelation function to store all the indices of higher correlation in a varibale. When I print this variable, I see that the indices are not sorted. I want to know how do I use this variable to select the columns from my original dataframe?

```
correlationMatrix <- cor(cor_numVar[,1:274])
highlyCorrelated <- findCorrelation(correlationMatrix, cutoff=0.5)
train[,highlyCorrelated]
```

Comment: use something lilke: `original_df[, sort(highlyCorrelated)]`

Comment: I am really sorry. Since I want to remove these highly correlated values, wanted to do something like this `original_df[, -sort(highlyCorrelated)]`
Meanwhile I found a solution by converting these indices to col names: 
`to_be_removed <- colnames(correlationMatrix)[highlyCorrelated]`
`original_df[!names(original_df) %in% to_be_removed]`


However, it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with `mtcars` dataset:

```
correlationMatrix <- cor(mtcars[, 2:10])
highlyCorrelated <- caret::findCorrelation(correlationMatrix, cutoff=0.5)
colnames(correlationMatrix)[-highlyCorrelated] #less correlated variables
colnames(correlationMatrix)[highlyCorrelated] #highly correlated variables
```